# picture viewer C++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

```
__fastcall TForm1::FillList() {
TSearchRec FoundedFile;
int r, i;
int count = 0;
int ir = 1;
char ext[3] = {'jpg', 'gif', 'png'};
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

r = FindFirst(Path + "*." + ext[i], faAnyFile, FoundedFile);

ListBox1->Items->Clear();
if (r == 0) {

    ListBox1->Items->Add(FoundedFile.Name);

    while (FindNext(FoundedFile) == 0) {
        ListBox1->Items->Add(FoundedFile.Name);

    }
    ListBox1->ItemIndex = 0;

    String File =
        String(Path + ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex]);
    //ShowMessage(File);
    Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile(File);
    count = ListBox1->Items->Count;
    }

}

if (ir == 0) {
    return -1;
}
else {
    count = ListBox1->Items->Count;
    return count;
}

}
```

Button won't read picture extension array ext[i]. 
Program doesn't show pictures with .gif, .png and .jpg extension. 
If there is no array and just r = FindFirst(Path + "(my extension)", faAnyFile, FoundedFile);, then it shows pictures with my extension.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fill the ListBox and display images in the same code.  It should be implemented as separate operations instead.  `FillList()` should only fill the ListBox, then you can display the selected image in the ListBox's `OnClick` event (there is no `OnChange` event, unless you subclass the ListBox to intercept the [`LBN_SELCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775161.aspx) notification directly), eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FillList()
{
    TSearchRec FoundedFile;
    int r, i;
    char* ext[3] = {"jpg", "gif", "png"};

    ListBox1->Items->BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        ListBox1->Items->Clear();

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            r = FindFirst(Path + "*." + ext[i], faAnyFile, FoundedFile);
            if (r == 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    ListBox1->Items->Add(FoundedFile.Name);
                }
                while (FindNext(FoundedFile) == 0);
                FindClose(FoundedFile);
            }
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        ListBox1->Items->EndUpdate();
    }

    ListBox1->ItemIndex = 0;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::ListBox1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int index = ListBox1->ItemIndex;
    if (index != -1)
    {
        String File = Path + ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex]);
        //ShowMessage(File);
        Image1->Picture->LoadFromFile(File);
    }
    else
        Image1->Picture->Assign(NULL);
}
```

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I was in a hurry, and was typing it on a tablet.  I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `char *ext[3] = {"jpg", "gif", "png"};` instead of `char ext[3] = {'jpg', 'gif', 'png'};`